# How to reuse Menu and Toolbar in different WPF UserControls with adding new buttons?

Tags: wpf, grid, controltemplate

I'm trying to port current *WinForms* app to *WPF* and need help with building *WPF* class structure.

Currently in WinForms, I have one *base class* (with Menu, Toolbar, Grid and Context menu) and several *inherited classes* with different datasources and columns for the grid and additional buttons for menu, toolbar and context menu.

Questions:

- What will be the best *WPF* class structure for my usercontrol to avoid inheritance?
- Can I move ToolBar into *ResourceDictionary* (e.g. *ControlTemplate*)?
  How to add new buttons or to bind commands to existed buttons, if buttons will be specified in a separate resource file?
- Any other ideas?

Due to inheritance restrictions in *WPF* I see only one way to avoid duplicating Menu, Toolbar, etc. - implement base class in C# code only without *XAML*. And likely I can't use XAML for inherited classes as well (have no idea how to add new buttons in XAML into Toolbar created in base class)

Comment: The WPF technology brought a bunch of new ideologies for WinForms developers. So instead of having a base class with common UI elements, some common behaviour and interaction logic, which we enhanced in inherited classes, we're going to have styles and components, which we use in other WPF pages. Styles can be enhanced or overridden late, but used components have to provide some flexibility to suit needs all classes/pages where they being used. 
Hence the initial question came from a newbie me and was due to not understanding the fundamentals, I'm closing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF a [Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.aspx) is an ItemsControl (same for [Menu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menu.aspx)), so it has an ItemsSource property you can bind to your collection of toolbar items.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}">
    <ToolBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate1}" ItemsSource="{Binding ToolbarItems}"/>
</Grid>
```

In this code, ToolbarItems is an ObservableCollection< MyToolBarItem >, where MyToolbarItem is a viewmodel that represents one toolbar item.

MyToolBarItem could be the base class, with several classes inheriting from it.  Then you can use a [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to use a different template depending on the type of toolbar item it is.

In this way, all your user controls that have a toolbar can use the same templates you define in your dictionary; each toolbar is just bound to a different collection of MyToolBarItems.

If some of that sounds overwhelming, you can read up on some [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).  It is the design pattern that makes WPF great.