# WPF MahApps.Metro Toolbar

Tags: wpf, toolbar, mahapps.metro

I want to use ToolBar 'User control' in WPF with MahApps.Metro

User Control:

```
<MahApps:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsToolbarTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:MahAppsToolbarTest="clr-namespace:MahAppsToolbarTest"
        xmlns:MahApps="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

Window:

```
<MahApps:MetroWindow x:Class="MahAppsToolbarTest.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:MahAppsToolbarTest="clr-namespace:MahAppsToolbarTest" xmlns:MahApps="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
<ToolBarTray>
<ToolBar>
<Button Content="Test button"/>
</ToolBar>
<MahAppsToolbarTest:TestToolbar/>
</ToolBarTray>
</Grid>
</MahApps:MetroWindow>
```

I want to use the same toolbar in multiple windows and I don't want just copy it.

You see the diff: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGJp0.png

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 ways to get what you want.

[image]

Using a `ContentControl` with a `ControlTemplate` defined in a resource dictionary

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ToolBarTemplate">
    <ToolBarTray>
        <ToolBar>
            <Button Content="Add"/>
            <Button Content="Delete"/>
            <Button Content="Save"/>
            <Button Content="Cancel"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You can now use this template where you want.

```
<ContentControl Template="{DynamicResource ToolBarTemplate}"
                Content="{Binding ViewModel4ToolBar}" />
```

Or using a `UserControl`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MetroDemo.ExampleWindows.ToolBarUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

        <ToolBarTray>
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Content="Add"/>
                <Button Content="Delete"/>
                <Button Content="Save"/>
                <Button Content="Cancel"/>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

usage

```
<local:ToolBarUserControl DataContext="{Binding ViewModel4ToolBar}" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want to have ToolBar as UserControl - I want to use it in another ToolBarTray with another ToolBars

Comment: It works, but it's not what I want - it impossible to add buttons to that user control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304280/how-to-reuse-menu-and-toolbar-in-different-wpf-usercontrols-with-adding-new-butt

Toolbar bound do collection of buttons works, but it's little diffrent stylized - I'm creating demo

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1Lrmx3D
Simple project that shows the difference between diffrent types of Toolbar.